# Mule esb and Transform message (wave transform component)

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

i have a problem working with transform message component and mule ESB that I do not understand.
I have a simple flow that works fine, at the beginning it is Http endpoint and at the end it is Transform message component, transforms one JSON to another.

Now when I try to store payload before transform message to variable and then set payload to that variable, I get exception on transform message component: 
Type mismatch
     found :name, :string
  required :name, :object (com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.DynamicDispatchNode:65 (null)

Here is a flow that works, and below that is the flow that doesn't work. 
Flow that works:

```
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="b8a77df6-4692-4c52-b572-b6a175e7467e" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    id: payload.transfer-id,
    created-record-status: 'accepter'
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Flow that doesn't work>

```
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <set-variable variableName="OriginalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.OriginalPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="b8a77df6-4692-4c52-b572-b6a175e7467e" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    id: payload.transfer-id,
    created-record-status: 'accepter'
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When i put logger to log payload before transformation, it is the same in both flows....
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the set payload is missing mime type you are getting the error use the below xml,I have tested and its working fine.`<set-payload value="#[flowVars.OriginalPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json"/>`

```
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Confi" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Confi" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="OriginalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.OriginalPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="b8a77df6-4692-4c52-b572-b6a175e7467e" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    id: payload.transfer-id,
    created-record-status: 'accepter'
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```